# Error when using extract function with argument regex: unused argument (regex =

Tags: r, regex, extract, data-wrangling

I tried to run the below code:

`library(tidyverse)`
`library(dplyr)`
`library(stringr)`
`library(tidyr)`
`tab %>% extract(x, c("feet", "inches"), regex = "(\\d)'(\\d{1,2})")`

and expected the following output:

```
 #> feet inches  
 #> 1 5 10  
 #> 2 6 1
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(., x, c("feet", "inches"), regex = "(\\d)'(\\d{1,2})", :  
 unused argument (regex = "(\\d)'(\\d{1,2})", remove = FALSE)
```

I tried googling the error but couldn't able to understand why it is showing that error. Please, help me in rectifying this error. Thanks in advance.

Data:

```
s <- c("5'10", "6'1")  
tab <- data.frame(x = s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quote character may need to be checked.  Otherwise, it should work with the reproducible example below

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tab %>%
    extract(x, c("feet", "inches"), regex = "(\\d)'(\\d{1,2})", convert = TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
   feet inches
  <int>  <int>
1     5     10
2     6      1
```

---

The error occurred because of loading `extract` from another package i.e. from `magrittr`. It is possible that the OP loaded both packages and the `magrittr::extract` masked the `tidyr::extract`

```
tab %>% 
   magrittr::extract(x, c("feet", "inches"), regex = "(\\d)'(\\d{1,2})", convert = TRUE)
```

> Error in `[.tbl_df`(., x, c("feet", "inches"), regex = "(\d)'(\d{1,2})",  :
> object 'x' not found

#### data

```
tab <- tibble(x = c("5'10", "6'1"))
```